# When i run my iPhone application it just show a white window, but when I press home button then it shows output what's wrong with it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My piece of code is...

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];  
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

view = [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:rect ];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
[window addSubview:view];

// Override point for customization after application launch
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete this:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```